# raspberry pi pico to pc communication

Tags: serial, pi-pico

I have a raspberry pi pico and want it to execute files on my windows pc(for example: if I press a button it opens a file). Because I am new to microcontrollers I have no idea how to do this. there is also no real tutorial trying to explain this. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please add an explanation of what this means to your question above ... `execute files on my windows pc` ... do not add explanation in a comment below

Answer (score 1):

Serial communication over the USB port is a great way to have your pi Pico talk to your pc. Also, before posting a question on Stack Exchange, look up what you are trying to do on google. I’m sure that there are plenty of guides that show you how to have your Pico and pc talk to each other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried but most of these tutorials use a serial monitor or let the pc communicate with the pico but I want the pico to communicate with my pc

Comment: I know that this is a little late, but try looking up having the pi pico communicate with Python.