# Use raspberry pi pico to open programs on host PC

Tags: usb, pi-pico, communication

I have both a raspberry pi pico and pico w, and am attempting to connect either one to a toggle switch, and use the input of said switch to either open or close an application on the host PC (preferably over the built in micro USB port used for programming the pico).
From all the research I’ve done the only people who’ve done pico to pc communication used it to drive a display on the pico (far above my pay grade: https://goldensyrupgames.com/blog/2022-02-04-pico-simple-two-way-serial/) or simply logged thonny console output on the host PC (which perhaps could work but seems a convoluted way of achieving my goal: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=310502).
I’ve seen plenty of people claim it should be easy or that there should be guides online (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151781/how-can-i-get-raspberry-pi-pico-to-communicate-with-pc-external-devices , [raspberry pi pico to pc communication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137563/raspberry-pi-pico-to-pc-communication)), but I’ve yet to find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a switch connected to the pc's usb port?

Answer (score 0):

For the Pi Zero you can use the remote GPIO feature of [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) or [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/gpio-expander/ for details.

For the Pico you can use the picod daemon and a Python script running on your PC.

See https://abyz.me.uk/picod/